# Nodejs, MongoDB (node-mongodb-native). FindAndModify finds doc, but doesn't update it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to use `findAndModify` operation to find and update doc.

```
Query: {'socket_id': data.socket_id, 'weapons.type': selectedWeapon, 'battleWeapons.type':selectedWeapon}
Update: {'$inc':{'weapons.$.nums':-1, 'battleWeapons.$.nums':-1}}
```

I got Doc in my callback function (so it found by query), but there's no changes in MongoDB doc. Same command works fine in mongo console. It changes everything I need. What am I doing wrong?

So the whole command looks like:

```
db.collection('users', function (err, collection) {
    var condition = {'socket_id': data.socket_id, 'weapons.type': selectedWeapon, 'battleWeapons.type':selectedWeapon},
    update = {'$inc':{'weapons.$.nums':-1, 'battleWeapons.$.nums':-1}};
    collection.findAndModify(condition, [['_id','asc']], update, {'new': true}, function (err, item) {...
})});
```

Answer (score 0):

In findAndModify, there is one more parameter which you can set, to return the old document(before update) or new document ( after update ). I am guessing this must be the issue. For confirmation, for the existing findAndModify() command, after this command is run, check that updated document from the mongo console, it must be changed.

Comment: If I run command in Mongo console everything changes fine, but if I run script nothing changes, I checked. Same values in DB, same document as before operation.